# Solve by factoring, then perform synthetic division.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${x^4 - 3x^3 + 3x^2 - x = 0}$$

$${x(x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1)}$$

Now, we have to perform synthetic division, if I'm correct we get the 1 to divide by from the X outside of the parentheses from the second equation, which is above this paragraph, and is also the factored form of the first equation.

$$\frac{x - 3 + 3 - 1}{1}$$

The answer is ${x = 0, 1}$. Does the 0 come from the remainder, and do the 1 come from the divisor?

Comment: Actually, that's $(x-1)^3$.

Comment: I don't get what you said! I copied everything out the book!

Comment: Try and expand $(x-1)^3$. Notice anything?

If your book doesn't factor it as $x(x-1)^3$, either I didn't understand the question or it's wrong.

Comment: Is this the right way to expand? ${(x • x = x^2)}{(x • 1 = 2x)}{(1 • 1 = 1)}{(x^2 - 2x + 1)}$

Comment: Your formatting is unreadable.  Consider using commas or empty space.  `~~~` can be used for empty space in expressions.  Also, `\cdot` instead of whatever bullet symbol you had used for multiplication.

Comment: @W.Zlacki Sorry, I can't read your text... The correct expansion is ${(x-1)^3=x^3-3x^2+3x-1}$, which is exactly what you have in your problem.

Comment: I'll start using \cdot on future post, since I'm new to it, and I don't want to mess it up. Plus, my IPhone is glitching!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synthetic division is not the greatest tool, in my opinion, because it makes the division process very mysterious. It's a shorthand for long division, and I would recommend writing out the steps of long division instead.

Anyway, to use synthetic division here, you can notice by plugging in a few values of $x$ that $x=1$ makes the cubic factor disappear: $1^3 - 3(1)^2 + 3(1) - 1 = 0$. On to synthetic division, with $1$ as the magic number:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & 1 & -3 & 3 & -1\\
1 &   & 1 & -2 & 1\\
\hline
  & 1 & -2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}$$

This means that $x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 - 2x +1)$. (There is no remainder term since the last number in the bottom right is $0$. For that matter, we knew in advance that there would be no remainder since $x=1$ is a zero.)

Now you could repeat the process with $x^2-2x+1$, but hopefully you recognize that $x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2$. Therefore, we have $x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = (x-1)^3$. Coming back to the original polynomial of degree $4$, we can see that:

$$x^4 - 3x^3 + 3x^2 - x = x(x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1) = x(x-1)^3.$$

The solutions $x=0,x=1$ come from the factors in this last expression ($x$ and $x-1$, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3-3x^2+3x-1=x^3-x^2-2x^2+2x+x-1=x^2(x-1)-2x(x-1)+(x-1)=(x-1)(x^2-2x+1)=(x-1)^3$$

Comment: The book does not show ${(x - 1)^3}$

Comment: It's an identity from high school.

Comment: I don't understand how you came up with ${(x - 1)^3}$ anyways.

Comment: ${(x - 1)(x^2 - 2x + 1) = (x - 1)^3}$ confused me.

Comment: $x^2-2x+1=x^2-x-x+1=x(x-1)-(x-1)=(x-1)^2$